# Spring WebFlux - Distinguish exception types

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactive-streams

I have to handle different exceptions in the Spring WebFlux chain. There is a `WebClient` and I need to have the logic, which would look like below code using the imperative style:

```
try {

} catch (WebClientResponseException e) {
   // flow 1
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
  // flow 2
} catch (Exception e) {
  // flow 3
}
```

The problem is that when building a reactive chain, I can only have one exception class or predicate:

```
...
.onErrorMap(WebClientResponseException.class, e -> {...})
.onErrorMap(Exception.class, e -> {...}) 
// will also be called for WebClientResponseException, which is not expected
```

Is it a common practice to use `instanceof` in these cases? Something like:

```
...
.onErrorMap(WebClientResponseException.class, e -> {...})
.onErrorMap(e -> !(e instanceof WebClientResponseException), e -> {...}) 
// will also be called for WebClientResponseException, which is not expected
```

OR

```
.onErrorMap(e -> {
   if (e instanceof WebClientResponseException) {
      // flow 1
   } else if (e instanceof TimeoutException) {
      // flow 2
   } else {
     // flow 3
   }
})
```

I believe in regular (non-reactive) java `instanceof` is considered to be a bad practice, however I do not see a better approach for the Reactive Stream.

Please share your thoughts